# XMPPFramework - Nickname not updated if vCard is not already created

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

Problem comes when a new user registers with XMPP. I am unable to set nickname on vCard, however if vCard of a user already exists then same piece of code works fine.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage *xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    XMPPvCardTempModule *xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
    [xmppvCardTempModule  activate:[self xmppStream]];

    XMPPvCardTemp *myVcardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];

    if (myVcardTemp == nil) {
       // I am stuck here, unable to create empty VCard for new User
    }
    else {
        [myVcardTemp setNickname:@"iphone"];
        [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myVcardTemp];
    }

});
```

Any clue for creating vcard for first time in xmpp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
if (!myvCardTemp) 
{
    NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
    XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
    [newvCardTemp setNickname:@"nick"];
    [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
}
else
{
    //Set Values as normal
}
```

Comment: Hello Haris, I have tried your code but it gives me warning at line         XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp =[XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML]; it says class method not found return type Id am i missing anything?

Comment: have you imported all the required files?

Comment: Hello Haris, I have used following code but seems its not creating card, it always go in new vcard.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code but seems its not creating card, it always go in if block, can you please looking to it if i am missing anything.

```
     XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
    [xmppvCardTempModule  activate:[self xmppStream]];
if (!myvCardTemp)
{
    NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
    XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp =[XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];

    [newvCardTemp setNickname:@"exist"];
    [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
    NSLog(@"no");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"yes");

    //Set Values as normal
    [myvCardTemp setNickname:@"new"];
    [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myvCardTemp];

}
```

Comment: You are loading vcard from xmppvCardTempModule before connecting it to stream, first activate it to stream and then load it
 [xmppvCardTempModule  activate:[self xmppStream]];
 XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
   
and dont post your queries in answers

Comment: Thanks for your help and time i will edit post once it resolve.. It still not working. can you please guide me.. my jid which is used is like test@server.com/15723468711390550376207526 so is it fine or it should be test@server.com

Comment: value after slash is resourceID, i think its different for every device, you dont have to add resource yourself, let it go as it is

Comment: Haris, Thanks for comment. I have kept it as it is. It seems like it is adding the card but the XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp]; is giving null always. But it receives the iq with the vcard as I set. any idea regarding it. once again thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello Haris, Thanks for your comment I have tried lot but still there is an issue, i have create new question for the same can you please look into it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21397543/695393